# Check if all visible cells in a range are equal to "Yes"?

Tags: excel

If I want to check if all cells (visible and hidden) in `B2:B30` are equal to `"Yes"` I know that I can use:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B30;"Yes")/(COUNTA(B2:B30)+COUNTBLANK(B2:B30))
```

But what formula can I use if I want to check if all *visible* cells in that range are equal to yes.

Comment: Are the rows hidden based upon some condition?

Comment: No condition, some rows are just hidden for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B30)-ROW(B2),0)),(B2:B30="Yes")+0)=SUBTOTAL(3,B2:B30),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Just realised that this only works for rows that are hidden **due to a filter**. This I presume is why it won't work for you.

Try this instead, should ignore the hidden rows now:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B30)-ROW(B2),0)),(B2:B30="Yes")+0)=SUBTOTAL(103,B2:B30),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

---

**EDIT 2**

This formula should show false if any blank cells exist in the range:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B30)-ROW(B2),0)),(B2:B30="Yes")+0)=SUBTOTAL(103,B2:B30), IF(SUMPRODUCT(((SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($C1,ROW($C$2:$C$30)-ROW($C$1),)))=1)*((SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B1,ROW(B$2:B$30)-ROW(B$1),)))=0))=0,"TRUE"),"FALSE")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that conplicated formula does, so am afraid to tweak it. I would like the formula to evaluate toTRUE if all visible cells in the range are equal to Yes and FALSE otherwise. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it an array formula? When I try the formula, it seems to count the number of "Yes", regardless if they are hidden cells or visible cells.

Comment: Thank you for trying. You're right, then it won't work.

Comment: My newest edit should hopefully fix the issue with the formula

Comment: It looks like it's closer. Thank you for trying! But if any or all visible cells are blank, it evaluates to TRUE. I only want it to evaluate to TRUE if all visible cells are "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a dirty trick, but it should work.

First, set `X2` (or some similarly far away cell) to `=IF(B2="Yes",0,"")` and copy this formula down the column to `X30`. Next, set all cells in `Y2:Y30` to `0`.

The formula `=IF(=AGGREGATE(2,5,X2:X30)=AGGREGATE(2,5,Y2:Y30),TRUE,FALSE)` will now evaluate to `TRUE` when all cells in the range `B2:B30` are equal to `"Yes"`, and `FALSE` when at least one is not equal to `"Yes"`.